# CAS JpaTicketRegistry not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, serialization, cas

I'm trying to install a CAS server version 4.0.0 instance, and configuring the ticket registry. The problem I'm facing happens with the `JpaTicketRegistry` when I try to login.

Basically, when I login, an `Authentication` object is created, and a `TicketGrantingTicket` is created for that Authentication, and it's supposed to be saved with the ticket registry. The `TicketGrantingTicket` has an `authentication` property that should be persisted as a `Lob`. The problem is that the `AuthenticationBuilder` which creates the `Authentication`, sets the `attributes` property in it with a `LinkedHashMap`, which includes the non-serializable class `LinkedKeySet`. Now, when the `JpaTicketRegistry` tries to persist the `TicketGrantingTicket`, it fails, because of a `SerializationException`.

The same problem arises when I tried to use `EhCacheTicketRegistry` with ehcache saving to disk for the same reason. Is there a way to overcome this problem, so that I can persist this object?

CAS 4.0 uses Hibernate 4.1.0 as the JPA implementation and Spring 3.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was as the following. In `org.jasig.cas.authentication.SuccessfulHandlerMetaDataPopulator`, the `populateAttributes` method adds the `keyset` of the `successes` map. The problem is that `keyset` is an instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet` which is not serializable, causing a `SerializationException` when trying to persist the `TicketGrantingTicket` after login while using the `JpaTicketRegistry` or even the `EHCacheTicketRegistry` with writing to disk enabled.

I created my own `AuthenticationMetaDataPopulator`, and created an [issue](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/issues/709) for the CAS team and created a [pull request](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/pull/710)